# Parse Date using lubridate - R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have dates in the format of:

```
"  4TH AUGUST 2014 "
"  1ST AUGUST 2014 "
```

How can I account for the `TH` and `ST` in the date?

**Work in progress:**

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(dt, "%d %B %Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(str_remove(dt, 'ST|TH|ND|RD'), "%d %B %Y")
[1] "2014-08-04 UTC" "2014-08-01 UTC"
```

Comment: yes, why does it not remove the `ST` in `AUGUST`?

Comment: it should also remove `ND` for second

Answer (score 1):

`lubridate`'s `dmy` can parse this.

```
x <- c("  4TH AUGUST 2014 ", " 1ST AUGUST 2014 ")
lubridate::dmy(x)
#[1] "2014-08-04" "2014-08-01"
```